# how do I set a window size of a multi-platform xcode app (spritekit)

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, window, size

how do I set the size of a multi-platform app in xcode (spritekit) ? I know that you can't change the window size on iphone but this app is multi-platform and can also run on macos. So how do I set the window size and make it unable to be stretched but able to full-screen? (on macos) and I was also wandering is there was a way to select the window's starting position. Thanks!

P.S. sorry for asking this stupid question just I'm a beginner so I don't know.

I had tried searching for an answer but I did not find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards you can specify a window controller's size and position as parameters in the Size inspector. To block stretching, turn the `Resize` control off in the Attributes inspector. Turning `Restorable` off also helps, otherwise AppKit will try to restore the previous state of the window frame.

Alternately, you can set the window size and origin programmatically, for instance in `NSViewController.viewDidLoad`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let size = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600)
    self.view.window?.setFrame(NSRect(origin: origin, size: size), display: true)
    self.view.window?.styleMask.remove([.resizable]) //turn off Resize control

}
```